# How to SQL join when join-id is nullable

Tags: sql, join, nullable

Struggling with a SQL query that won't join

```
SELECT * 
FROM AspNetUsers u
JOIN Groups g ON g.Id = u.GroupId
```

In the `AspNetUsers` table, I have these columns:

```
Id INT
GroupId INT (nullable)
```

In the `Groups` table, I have:

```
Id INT
GroupName VARCHAR(255)
```

(There is a FK set up between the `userId` and `GroupId` so no type mismatch)

I get this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'Groups g ON g.Id = u.GroupId

Can I not join on a nullable column? I just want to retrieve those rows where there is a matching GroupId. How would you go about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong, but: `groups` is MySQL **reserved word** (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)) which means that it can't be used for table or column name; I'd say that this is the reason for error you got. *Maybe* you should enclose table name into double quotes (and match letter case)?

As of your question: certainly, you *can* perform join on `NULL` values; you just won't get any result. In that case, see whether **outer join** helps in what you're doing.

Comment: Indeed doing Groups with escaping solved my issue. Many thanks!